# Not receiving all data from IGDB Api using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am building an app using the IGDB Api to get a list of games to display in the app. I am using  the retrofit library as well. Currently I am trying to get the game cover being displayed in a GridView but for some reason I get null from the Api as result when I am calling for the cover URL and also other data except "id". Can anybody help me finding out why I am getting null? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I think there might an issue getting data from IGDB. I realised when I set an empty string in `Call<ArrayList<Game>> call = service.getAllGames(FIELDS);` I get the same results, where I only get the ID. Can't figure out why though :/

Game.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Game {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("cover")
    @Expose
    private Cover cover;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    @Expose
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("summary")
    @Expose
    private String summary;
    @SerializedName("genres")
    @Expose
    private List<Genre> genres = null;
    @SerializedName("platforms")
    @Expose
    private List<Platform> platforms = null;
    @SerializedName("rating")
    @Expose
    private Double rating;
    @SerializedName("release_dates")
    @Expose
    private List<ReleaseDate> releaseDates = null;
    @SerializedName("videos")
    @Expose
    private List<Video> videos = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Cover getCover() {
        return cover;
    }

    public void setCover(Cover cover) {
        this.cover = cover;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public List<Genre> getGenres() {
        return genres;
    }

    public void setGenres(List<Genre> genres) {
        this.genres = genres;
    }

    public List<Platform> getPlatforms() {
        return platforms;
    }

    public void setPlatforms(List<Platform> platforms) {
        this.platforms = platforms;
    }

    public Double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Double rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public List<ReleaseDate> getReleaseDates() {
        return releaseDates;
    }

    public void setReleaseDates(List<ReleaseDate> releaseDates) {
        this.releaseDates = releaseDates;
    }

    public List<Video> getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }

    public void setVideos(List<Video> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }

}
```

Cover.java:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Cover {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

GameAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.R;
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.data.Game;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.GameAdapterViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Game> mGameData;
    private Context mContext;

    public GameAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Game> gameData) {
        mContext = context;
        mGameData = gameData;
    }

    public class GameAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mGameCover;

        public GameAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mGameCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game_cover_image);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GameAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.game_list_item;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, parent, false);
        return new GameAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cover cover = mGameData.get(position).getCover();
    String currentGame = null;
    if (cover != null)
        currentGame = cover.getUrl();
    Picasso.get()
            .load(currentGame)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
            .error(R.drawable.image_not_found)
            .into(holder.mGameCover);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mGameData == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mGameData.size();
    }

}
```

PopularGamesFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.R;
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.adapter.GameAdapter;
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.data.Game;
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.network.GameInstance;
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.network.GetDataService;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class PopularGamesFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private TextView mErrorTextMessage;

    private GameAdapter mGameAdapter;

    public static final String FIELDS = "fields name, platforms.name, cover.url, rating, release_dates.human, genres.name, summary, popularity, time_to_beat, videos.name, videos.video_id;";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular_games, container, false);

        GetDataService service = GameInstance.getGameInstance().create(GetDataService.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Game>> call = service.getAllGames(FIELDS);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Game>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Game>> call, Response<ArrayList<Game>> response) {
                mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                generateDataList(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Game>> call, Throwable t) {
                mErrorTextMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.popular_games_error_message);
                mErrorTextMessage.setText("Something went wrong. Try again!");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void generateDataList(ArrayList<Game> gameList) {
        mGameAdapter = new GameAdapter(getActivity(), gameList);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mGameAdapter);
    }

}
```

GameInstance.java

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class GameInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api-v3.igdb.com/";

    public static Retrofit getGameInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

GetDataService

```
import com.riceplant.capstoneproject.data.Game;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface GetDataService {

    @Headers("user-key: GET YOU DATA KEY FROM IGDB")
    @POST("games")
    Call<ArrayList<Game>> getAllGames(@Body String fields);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `fields` body - parameter on the `GetDataService`.

The documentation (https://api-docs.igdb.com/?kotlin#game) states that you should always put in a field body, to filter the fields you want to display.

I'd recommend starting to get the REST requests correct first, by using Postman or curl: First use the tool to form the request so that the response fits your expectations, and only then start creating the actual app implementation.

So the steps would be: Request all the games using the /games endpoint specifying all the fields as a body to the POST request. Once you got the id for the covers, request /covers and filter for the covers you actually want to display, afaik.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, I actually use postman to get the REST request. the fields I am using is the following `fields name, platforms.name, cover, cover.url, rating, release_dates.human, genres.name, summary, popularity, time_to_beat, videos.name, videos.video_id;` do you mean I should use the @Field annotation?

Comment: alright I got what you meant; I changed the GetDataService call to `Call<ArrayList<Game>> getAllGames(@Query("fields") String fields);` and in PopularGamesFragment I changed the string FIELDS to `public static final String FIELDS = "name, platforms.name, cover, cover.url, cover.image_id, rating, release_dates.human, genres.name, summary, popularity, time_to_beat, videos.name, videos.video_id;";`
Thank you a lot!