# Retrofit2 POST String body

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm making a POST request to the IGDB api which returns a JSON List. If the POST request has an empty body, it will return only the id in incremental order like this.
[image: postman request with body]

[image: postman request without body]

I tried passing the body as a String on my Api Interface like so

```
interface GameApiClient {


    @Headers(
        "Client-ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Accept: */*"
    )
    @POST("games")
    suspend fun getAllGames(@Body query: String): Response<List<Game>>
}
```

```
class GameService {


    private val retrofit = RetrofitHelper.getRetrofit()

    suspend fun getGames(): List<Game> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = retrofit.create(GameApiClient::class.java)
                .getAllGames("fields id, name; where status = (0, 2, 3, 4); offset  0; where rating>0;")
            response.body() ?: emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns it as if I didnt pass any body to the interface [image: Response inside android studio]

Comment: Have you tried passing the body as a map? or as a custom class object?

Comment: Also, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393852/not-receiving-all-data-from-igdb-api-using-retrofit

Comment: @gioravered funnily enough the Query("Fields") work but I dont wrap my head around it modifying the url of the api -> https://api.igdb.com/v4/games?fields=id%2C%20name%3B. Do you perhaps know why this is? also since there can be multiple statements like wheres, or offset, im not entirely sure how im supposed to do the interface.

Comment: @Query mean a query parameter. It is added to the URL (after the > sign) and doesn't affect the URL destination. Can you elaborate on what it is that you want to do now?

Comment: I cant apply the where conditions neither with ```@Body``` nor ```@Query```, I can only modify the fields im retrieving from the api using the ```@Query("Fields")```. I want to be able to pass a where condition based on the method im using.

Comment: Are you able to make it work using Postman? or other REST client?

Comment: Yes, as seen on the first image, passing all my intended "queries" on a raw body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a RequestBody with the MediaType text/plain and it works ok.

```
    suspend fun getGames(): List<Game> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.get("text/plain; charset=utf-8"), "fields id, name, summary; where status = (0, 2, 3, 4);")
            val response = retrofit.create(GameApiClient::class.java)
                .getAllGames(body)
            response.body() ?: emptyList()
        }
    }
```